# Sum of odd integers

Tags: java

I need to complete a method which is passed an int(max) as a parameter and returns the sum of the odd integers from 1 to max (inclusive).

For example, `sumOfOddIntegers(5)` must return 9. i.e. 1 + 3 + 5 = 9

My attempt was this:

```
int sumOfOddIntegers(int max) {
  int sumOdd = 0; 
  int digit; 
  while (max >= 1) { 
    digit = max%10; 
    if (digit%2 == 1)
      sumOdd += digit; 
    max /= 10; 
  }

  return sumOdd;
}
```

But it does not work with some inputs such as 5, 9, etc. What do I need to change in my code?

Comment: what is the max?? and why max /=10??

Comment: Your algorithm is not doing what you stated in your problem. Currently, it is trying to get the sum of all the odd digits which contains the number. Please verify your algorithm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to get s sum of odd number, you are not required to do digit = max%10; or max/= 10;

See the comments in your code, let say max = 98

```
   /****FIRST RUN****/
   // digit = 98%10 = 8
   digit = max%10; 
   // 8 % 2 == 0
   if( digit % 2 == 1 ) 
     sumOdd += digit; 
   // max = 98/10 = 9
   max/= 10; 

   /****SECOND RUN****/
   // digit = 9%10 = 9
   digit = max%10; 
   // 9 % 2 == 1
   if( digit % 2 == 1 ) 
     // sumOdd = 1
     sumOdd += digit; 
   // max = 9/10 = 0
   max/= 10;
```

Your output is 1, which is not what you expect.
Hence, in order to compute sum of odd number you can proceed via:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= max; i+= 2)
{
   oddSum += i; // assuming oddSum = 0, and max is > 0
}
```

Answer (score 10):

why not just do this the easy way. Find the number of odd numbers in the range from 1 to `max` and then square it. This might help you http://www.wikihow.com/Add-a-Sequence-of-Consecutive-Odd-Numbers

Comment: +1: Doesn't give the direct solution to OP instead gives the info in order to OP could solve its homework.

Answer (score 0):

here is some code

```
void calculateOdd(int max) {
  int total = 0;
  for (int i=max; i>0; i--) {
    if ( (i % 2) != 0 ) total+=i;
 }
 }
```

or

```
void calculateOdd(int max) {
  int total = 0;
  if ( (max % 2) == 0 ) max--;
  for (int i=max; i>0; i--) {
     total+=i;
     i--;
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Write a method that will take a number as input, and will check whether or not it's odd. If the number is odd, it may return true, otherwise it may return false (HINT: odd numbers aren't divisible by 2).
2. From your current method, loop from 1 to `max`. Pass each number to this method to check if it's odd or not. If it is, add it to the sum.

Answer (score 0):

Might be this helps :

```
import java.util.*;

class oddsum {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int sumOdd = 0;
        int digit;

        System.out.println("Please Enter Number.");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());

        int j;
        for(j =1; j<=i; j+=2) {
            sumOdd += j;
        }

        System.out.println(sumOdd);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the sum of odd integers from `1` to `max`, you can use the Java 8 [`Stream`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html)

```
  public static int sumOddIntegers(int max){
        if(max<1) return 0;
        return IntStream.rangeClosed(1, max).filter(i -> i%2 != 0).sum();
    }
```

The following method calls are used:

- `IntStream.rangeClosed(1, max)` to generate a stream of `int` from 1 to `max`.
- `filter(i->i%2!=0)` to keep only odd `int`
- `sum()` to make the sum.

You then find the right values.

Comment: I think they have to write an own function